# Positive definite matrix and Hörmander theory

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, differential-operators

Let $\varphi \in C_{0}^{\infty}, \varphi\neq 0$. We'll consider the inner product in $L^{2}.$

Let $\alpha,\beta$ multi-index, $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\alpha|,|\beta|\leq m$ and set
$$
\varphi_{\alpha\beta}= \left\langle \dfrac{D^{\alpha}}{\alpha!},\dfrac{D^{\beta}}{\beta!}\right\rangle=\dfrac{1}{\alpha!\beta!}\int D^{\alpha}\varphi \overline{D^{\beta}\varphi}dx.
$$
Now consider $t=(t_{\alpha})$ a "array" of complex numbers, such that $t_{\alpha}=t_{\alpha^{\prime}},$ where $\alpha^{\prime}$ is a permutation of $\alpha$ and define
$$
\displaystyle u(x)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}t_{\alpha}D^{\alpha}\varphi(x)
$$
Define the quadratic form in $t$ defined by
$$
Q(t)=Q((t_{\alpha}))= \sum_{i \alpha_{i} \leq m} \sum_{i \beta \mid \leq m} t_{\alpha} \overline{t_{\beta}} \varphi_{\alpha \beta}.
$$
How to prove that in this conditions, holds
$$
\sum_{|\alpha| \leq m} \sum_{\beta\leq m} t_{\alpha} \overline{t_{\beta}} \varphi_{\alpha \beta}=\int\bigg|\sum_{|\alpha| \leq m} \dfrac{t_{\alpha} D_{\alpha} \varphi}{|\alpha| !}\bigg|^{2} d x \hspace{2mm} ? 
$$
I saw this in Hörmander's Thesis, this is theorem 2.2 in page 179. He just say that this equality holds, but I can't see that.

I don't need to use that fact, I just want to prove that this quadratic form is positive definite to use coerciveness.

Can anybody help me, please?

P.S: I know that matrix $(\varphi_{\alpha\beta})$ is hermitian, normal and diagonalizable. But I couldn't prove that the eigenvalues are strictly positive.

Comment: Expand the RHS and use the definition of $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}$.

Comment: In other words: write the $|{\rm sum}|^2$ inside the integral as a product of two sums with two different multiindices.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you, sir!

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you, sir!